# scheme functions

Tags: string, function, scheme

I have defined `is-string?`:

```
(define (is-string? expr)
  (string? expr))
```

and also `interpret-string`:

```
(define (interpret-string expr env)
  expr)
```

These are the functions I have written:

```
(define (string-equals? expr)
  (and
    (list? expr)
    (= 3 (length expr))
    (equal? '= (first expr))))

(define (interpret-string expr env)
  (=
    (internet (second expr) env)
    (interpret (third expr) env)))
```

This is the interpreter for string:

```
((is-string? expr) (interpret-string expr env))
```

When I enter this line to check whether it works:

```
(check-expect (is-string-equals? ’(string-equals "abc" "abc"))
              #t)
```

I get an error saying:

```
check-expect encountered the following error instead of the expected value, #t. 
   :: reference to undefined identifier: is-string-equals?
```

What would I have to do for `is-string-equals`? I have no clue.

here is the actual question asked as requested.

1. Extend the interpreter with a “string” datatype. You will need to write functions:
2. is-string?
3. interpret-string
   and modify the interpret function to support the string datatype.
   Also add two functions to work with strings within the interpreted language:
4. string-equals? to check if two given strings are the same.
5. string-join to return a new string formed by joining two strings togeter.
   Make sure your functions pass the following tests:

   (check-expect (is-string-equals? ’(string-equals "abc" "abc"))
                 #t)

   (check-expect (interpret-string-equals ’(string-equals "abc" "abc") (make-env))
                 #t)

Comment: You don't have a function called `is-string-equals?`, but you _do_ have one called `string-equals?`, albeit it looks strange from the above definition. And what's with the `interpret-string` procedure?. It's not clear *at all* what you want to test in `check-expect`

Comment: A string is not a list of characters.

Answer (score 2):

I see where this is going--this is for a PL class, and you're extending an existing interpreter so that it can handle strings and string comparisons--but it looks to me like it would help you *a lot* to add purpose statements to your functions, and test cases for all of them.  Start at the top.  What is `is-string?` supposed to do? Write test cases to make sure it does what it's supposed to. Work your way down.

Also, shame on your instructor for giving you test cases :).